# What is the meaning of "c'est à vendre ou c'est pas à vendre faut pas se foutre du monde"?

Tags: sens

I came across the phrase *c'est à vendre ou c'est pas à vendre faut pas se foutre du monde* concerning a certain product and was wondering what it means. Two possibilities i could think of were:

1. Nobody (as of the customers) is concerned if it's for sale or not.
2. One (the manufacturer) is not concerned whether it's for sale or not.

Comment: 1- What part of the sentence is bothering you: "*c'est à vendre ou c'est pas à vendre*" or "*faut pas se foutre du monde*"? 2- Can you give more context? As it stands it's most likely a potential customer wanting to know if the seller actually wants to sell or not.

Comment: Who wrote the sentence: was it the manufacturer, or a potential client?

Comment: @ChrisW A client interested with the product as the  potential seller already knows the answer.

Comment: @Laure I didn't realize that there were two parts and thought of it as one expression. I get the meaning when they stand on their own. Gilles answer clarified this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very informal French. It's written without punctuation, so the first step is to add it back:

> C'est à vendre ou c'est pas à vendre ? Faut pas se foutre du monde !

The first sentence is asking whether ”it“ (an object which should be clear from the context) is for sale. The question structure with the subject before the verb is the informal question structure of French, where only the intonation marks that the sentence is a question rather than a statement. The repetition “is it … or is it not …?” is generally emphatic, and specifically connotes insistence: the person who is asking wants an answer now.

The second sentence can roughly be translated semi-literally as “you must not bullshit people”, and really means “stop bullshitting people” or “stop bullshitting me”. “*Se foutre de*” can mean many things, centered around not caring about something or someone; it's always highly informal and quite rude. In “*se foutre du monde*”, it means doing something outrageous; despite the presence of *monde* (world) the outrage might only be felt by a single person (it's an idiom).

Thus the potential customer is casting doubt as to the seller's willingness to sell, and accusing the seller of doing something wrong — at least of wasting the potential customer's time. All of this very impolitely.

Comment: I guess we could add that the customer sounds angry.

Answer (score 3):

It is obviously part of a seller/customer altercation. A product was for sale but for some reason (unreasonable bargaining down of the price maybe? wrong price tag?) the seller changed his mind and refused to sell it.  Hence the buyer's reaction: Is it for sale or not? Cut the crap!